# Free memory from tensorflow tensors before session ends

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
tf version: 1.14.0
keras version: 2.2.4
```

I'm running out of memory with tensorflow.

Essentially, I'm calling a tool multiple times, and each time the tool adds more tensors to the tensorflow graph. I'm wondering if there's a way to delete (and clear from memory) individual tensors on the tensorflow graph without resetting the whole graph.

The reason why I don't want to reset the whole graph is that I have a keras model loaded onto the graph and I don't want to reload the model at every iteration

I've tried fiddling with tensorflow's eager execution, but I'm loading a pretrained keras model with placeholders, so that's incompatible.

Additionally, the tensors created by the tool are based on the keras model, so I'm unable to use multiple graphs.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

def num_of_tensors():
    # Gets the number of tensors in the graph
    graph_names = [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]

    print(len(graph_names))


# Any model will work here.
model = keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

num_of_tensors()

gradients = tf.gradients(model.outputs, model.inputs)

num_of_tensors()

del gradients

# Even after you delete the gradients, the tensors are not cleared.
num_of_tensors()
```